# string format of Date

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert from a log file date format to an object dateTime

however I cannot find the string format to use in order to convert it?

can someone please help me with the format:

log file line: - Started 28/12/2014 16:53:47.48 "

my code:

```
 string pattern1 = @"(\d+)[/](\d+)[/](\d+)";
 Match match1 = Regex.Match(lineOfLog, pattern1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 if (match1.Success)
 {
   string dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.zzz";
   string dateString = match1.Groups[1].Value;
   DateTime date = new DateTime();
   try
   {
    date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }

    catch
    {

    }

  }
```

exception: "string was not recognized as a valid date Time

Comment: can you show what dateString becomes when you are trying to convert it?

Comment: no. I am getting an exception...:(

Comment: At which line you are getting error at?

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/r/2qfN4wD7rkpQ1EOl here your regex you're getting is only date and you're using datetime parse exact that is expecting time also that might be reason

Comment: `(\d+)[/](\d+)[/](\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)` use this regex

Comment: Your regex is invalid, it matches only "28" (first digits), not the full date.
Therefore it can't work : captured data doesn't match date pattern. Fix the regex.

Comment: @KaushikKishore > caution ! your regex won't work too : if you put parenthesis around tokens, each of them will generate a single capture group, and OP needs the date in a single one ! Here is a regex which should be ok : (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d*) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three issues here:

- the regex doesn't capture the entire date and time
- you're just getting one part of the regex result (i.e. you're getting a single group instead of the value for the entire match)
- your format string uses `zzz` when it should be `FF` for hundredths or `FFF` for thousands

Try something like this:

```
string lineOfLog = "- Started 28/12/2014 16:53:47.48";
string dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FF";           
string pattern1 = @"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)";

Match match1 = Regex.Match( lineOfLog, pattern1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
if( match1.Success )
{
    var dateString = match1.Value; // note the change here
    var d = DateTime.ParseExact( dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
}
```

Note that you could omit the `()`'s completely, they don't really do any good, but they do make the regex easier to read (IMHO).

Comment: Thats the answer. I was going to answer same. 1 change : dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FF, milliseconds part should be according to incoming milliseconds. For example, for 28/12/2014 16:53:47.48, use  dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FF and for 28/12/2014 16:53:47.481 use dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF